# Passing values to API

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make an API call to "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2975590&apikey= I wanted to know if someone could show me how I could pass in the i parameter via javascript code. Currently i=tt2975590.

```
let detailMovie= "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2975590&apikey=<mykey>    
let request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('Get',movieURL)
request.send()
request.onload = function() {
    if(request.status !=200){
        console.log("There is a problem")
    } else {
        let moviesResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
        I want to be able to call http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2975590&apikey=<mykey> but pass in the paramater(i) value.
    }
}
```

enter code here

Comment: request.open('Get',movieURL) should be request.open('Get', detailMovie)

Comment: isn't it that you are already passing "i" as a querystring?

Answer (score 0):

**use the** `${}`

```
let key = "1234";
let apikey = "878234";
let detailMovie = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${key}&apikey=${apikey}`;
console.log(detailMovie);
```

**or use a function that returns the api**

```
function genApi(key, apikey) {
   return `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${key}&apikey=${apikey}`;
}
```

the function example can be assing as meny times as you with so

```
const myApi = genApi("123", "23423"); 
// will be "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=123&apikey=23423"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios to ease api calling.
Here a snippet of how you can pass in params to a get request.

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID

axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });

// Optionally the request above could also be done as
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of i in some variable like:

var x = 'tt2975590';

then use it in your URL like,

let detailMovie= "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="+z+"&apikey="

use the above detailMovie variable to open your request.

Answer (score 0):

Few browser has deprecated the `XMLHttpRequest()`, so its better and highly recommend to use fetch API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
You can pass values with url using `URLSearchParams(params)`.
For example

```
var url = new URL('https://sl.se')

var params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431} // or:
var params = [['lat', '35.696233'], ['long', '139.570431']]

url.search = new URLSearchParams(params)


fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then((text) => {
    console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', text)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('request failed', error)
  })
```